# python random.getstate() and random.setstate()

Tags: python-3.x, random

Learning the module random here, in the very beginning there are book-keeping functions, I understand that to set a specific seed is to make sure obtaining same random number.

but, what about the `getstate()` and `setsate()`? [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#bookkeeping-functions)
In the documentation, it has no introduction for what this state means, and if I don't know what it means, how could I set it right?

> ***random.getstate()***
>
> Return an object capturing the current internal state of the
>   generator. This object can be passed to setstate() to restore the
>   state.
>
> ***random.setstate(state)***
>
> state should have been obtained from a previous call to getstate(),
>   and  setstate() restores the internal state of the generator to what
>   it was at the time getstate() was called.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try it out?

```
import random

random.seed(42)

print(random.sample(range(20),k=10))

st = random.getstate()  # remeber this state 

print(random.sample(range(20),k=20)) # print 20

random.setstate(st)     # restore state

print(random.sample(range(20),k=10)) #print same first 10
```

Output:

```
[12, 0, 4, 3, 11, 10, 19, 1, 5, 18]
[4, 9, 0, 3, 10, 8, 16, 7, 18, 17, 14, 6, 2, 1, 5, 11, 15, 13, 19, 12]
[4, 9, 0, 3, 10, 8, 16, 7, 18, 17]
```

Obvoiusly, you can go back and reproduce the same values over and over if you get a state and restore it.

You can not use different randoms in between though or you alter the state.

```
random.setstate(st) # go back again

print(random.sample(range(99),k=2)) # do something different
print(random.sample(range(20),k=18))
```

Output:

```
[21, 50]      # something different after setting state
[0, 3, 11, 9, 18, 8, 17, 19, 16, 7, 15, 1, 10, 2, 12, 5, 13, 14] # changed values
```

---

```
import random
import timeit

t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt = """random.seed(42)
random.randint(1,10)""",number=10000,setup="import random")

t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt = """
random.randint(1,10)
random.setstate(s)""",number=10000,setup="""import random
s = random.getstate()""")

print(t1,t2)
```

Output:

```
# seed() time           setstate() time
0.5621587821914207      0.49502014443357545
```

Comment: Oh! So set state is not to edit the state, it is just to apply this state again! Thanks! Because When I print out the state, it outputs a lot of numbers, I don't know how to "set" those numbers!

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 You get the state and set it again. Read the desc of `setstate(state)` again ;)

Comment: But I can see you also used `random.seed(42)` in the beginning, why is that? And does the state include the seed number?

Comment: And If I replace both of your `getstate()` and `setstate()` with `random.seed(43)`, it will output the same way, so what is the point of using the sate other than just to set the same `seed()` every time?

Comment: Got it, so basically the state is a convenient way to remember a seed, it does not do anything else that seed can't do?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 see edit. setstate is slightly faster. but I guess you could use seed instead.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 The state doesn't remember the seed, the seed is used to initialize the state.  The generator works on state, not on the seed, from that point forward.

Comment: @pjs lpease point me to where I said seed = state .. You could use random.seed(42) to get back to a defined state and start again. Nevermind - found it - unable to edit so deleted it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You cannot use random.seed() to continue from a particular later point in the sequence of pseudo-randomness without re-doing all calls you did, for example random.shuffle(), random.random(), random.randrange(), random.choice(). That's were getstate() and setstate() come in.

Answer (score 15):

Python's default generator is a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) with a state space that is 19937 bits, much larger than what you think of as the seed.

You can think of it conceptually as three functions:

- f(seed) -> state<sub>0</sub>
- g(state<sub>i</sub>) -> state<sub>i+1</sub>
- h(state<sub>i</sub>) -> outcome<sub>i</sub>

When you start with a seed value using `random.seed()`, it generates a full state value of 19937 bits **one time** using function f(). Each time you use the generator, it advances to the next 19937 bit state using g() and returns the output found by collapsing the updated state down a single integer using h().

Normally you don't actually see the internal state which is at the core of the generator. `getstate()` bypasses the collapsing function h(), and `setstate()` bypasses the seeding function f(), so that you can reproduce your sequence from any point without having to go all the way back to the beginning and reproduce the entire sequence to that point.

Most people don't need to (and shouldn't) use the get/setstate capability, but it can be useful for pulling some clever mathematical tricks to [reduce variability of Monte Carlo estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction).

Comment: Thank you! That explained why using state() is faster than using seed() every time.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I like to know how things work, in addition to how you use them.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Only use states obtained with getstate(). Unless you are an expert on PRNGs and checked the source code you may create an invalid state that produces low quality randomness or even triggers an exception.

Comment: f(seed) does different things depending on the type of seed. For many types including strings, the built-in hash() function is used, which only yields 64 bit. Use large positive integers to have more impact on the state.