# will randint always generate random numbers?

Tags: python, random

Does `random.randint` have a cooldown (or so) time before it generates a new random/seed?

As a part of something bigger I am trying to program a list of 5 "dice rolls" (random numbers from 1 to 6). I have this code in my program:

```
from random import randint

rolls = [randint(1,6),randint(1,6),randint(1,6),randint(1,6),randint(1,6)]
print (rolls)
```

When checking things i rolled 1,2,3,4,5 twice in a row and then i checked other rolls and the numbers didnt seem to change much between each roll

Comment: I would put them in a loop rather than calling them distinctly. Could affect randomness.

Comment: For reference... `rolls = [ randint(1,6) for i in range(6) ]`

Comment: @KuboMD How can that make a difference?

Comment: See [the doc on random.seed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) which says that unless  you manually enter a seed, the current time is used. So the seeding is based on the current time when you call `randint`

Comment: @glglgl was just a guess :)

Comment: I tried it and the results look pretty random to me: https://ideone.com/z6p89d. And since each roll is distinct from the others, `1,2,3,4,5` is random.

Comment: @KuboMD Well, it doesn't: https://ideone.com/ADO3jH

Comment: Did you run the output through a statistical test for randomness? Genuinely random output tends to have more patterns (e.g. runs of a particular number) than many people think it should have ("chance is lumpy" is one of [Abelson's laws](https://mattdickenson.com/2013/05/27/statistics-as-principled-argument/)). Intuition is not always a reliable guide to detecting randomness.

Comment: "didnt seem to change much" What do you mean by "change much"? Either they changed or they stayed the same. If you run the script multiple times within the same second, the RNG will be seeded with the same time.

Comment: @KuboMD: he is rolling 5 die, you are rolling 6.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark: The documentation says nothing about seeding with the current time when **randint** is called, and that is likely not the case.

Comment: @JamesKPolk seeding will affect all the random functions in the `random` module. It doesn't explicitly list out all the functions. [Here's the source code for the random module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py). As you can see in the `Random` class, any method will be initialized by calling seed. `randint` is a method of `Random`, meaning it will get seeded using the `seed` function I linked prior.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark: Tell me the line number of the that file that calls `seed` when any method is called.

Comment: @JamesKPolk [Line 93 shows `seed` is called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py) in `Random.__init__`. `randint` is a method of `Random`, so `__init__` will be called prior to `randint`.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark: ok, but that is only called **once** when the instance is created, not every time a method is called.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of misconceptions about how PRNGs work and what seeding does.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505649/2166798 for an explanation.