# What does happen if seed value is not declared throughout in a python code?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, random-seed

```
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 
nums = [] 

mu = 0
sigma = 2
    
for i in range(100): 
    temp = random.gauss(mu, sigma)
    nums.append(temp) 
         
plt.plot(nums) 
plt.show()
```

Here, I haven't declared the seed value. So, will it consider
different seed values at each iteration of `i` ? In this kind of
simulation, or say in long Monte Carlo simulations, is it recommended to
choose different values of seeds instead of a particular fixed seed
value ?

Comment: Set the seed (once at the beginning) only if you want the script to produce the same sequence of numbers each time you run it.  If that doesn't matter, don't set the seed.

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you have a conceptual misunderstanding of pseudo-random number generators and seeding.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505649/2166798) for an explanation of the role of seeding.

Comment: Thanks. @hpaulj Sir, however,  I was wondering in order to write monte carlo codes such as, say, random walk problem or noise amplitude generation, would it be better to choose  a different or new value of seeds at every next iteration ? Thanks.

Comment: @pjs ; Thanks for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't initialize the pseudo-random generator using `random.seed()` then Python will attempt to get a random seed from the operating system, failing that it will use the system time.

List of random numbers without a seed:

```
import random
for i in range(5):
    print(random.randint(1,50))
```

Output:

```
19
44
33
12
42
```

If you want reproducible results for your experiment/simulation then it's advisable to initialize the pseudo-random number generator with a known seed value.

Reproducible list of random numbers using a seed value:

```
import random
for i in range(5):
    random.seed(13)
    print(random.randint(1,50))
```

Output:

```
17
17
17
17
17
```

This demonstrates that Python's `random` module does not produce truly random numbers, it's predictable if you know the seed value.

**PCG (Permuted Congruential Generator)**

[PCG](https://www.pcg-random.org/) is a family of statistically good algorithms for random number generation that are hard to predict, it can be found in the `numpy.random` module. Here's some code to generate a normal distribution using a generator seeded with an unpredictable value provided by the `secrets` module. The generator can also be used for a range of [probability distributions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html?highlight=generator#distributions).

```
import secrets
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64

random_seed = secrets.randbits(64) # An integer with 64 random bits
random_gen = Generator(PCG64(random_seed))

data = random_gen.normal(size=10000)
```

Comment: It seems like then to formulate monte carlo data on random walk or noise amplitude generation, using an unfixed value of seed (i.e. not declaring any see value at all in the code) would be better, Right ?

Comment: There is a pattern in the pseudo random number generators and if you have a sufficiently long sequence, the pattern will emerge. The `secrets` module generates cryptographically strong random numbers and would be a better option for more random numbers. If you want truly random numbers then use an external input source such as a microphone or an antenna to measure radio signals. The world outside the computer is the best source of entropy.

Comment: How shall I use to secrets module to generate a particular type of distribution of random numbers ? i.e  `secrets.random.gauss(mu, sigma)` sort of ?

Comment: The `secrets` model isn't meant for modeling or simulations, it generates unpredictable data so it's a good seed value. I've updated my answer to include an example with a better random number generation technique PCG.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however kindly let me ask one more thing, `import random
for i in range(5):
    random.seed(13)
    print(random.randint(1,50))` -- What if I set seed() at the starting of the code, i.e. say, befor the range of 'i' ? will the code consider that particular seed() value throughout the code / compilation ?

Comment: In that case the loop will display 5 numbers from the pseudo random number generator with the seed value of 13. The numbers will continue to be drawn from that list until the Random object is reseeded.

Comment: the numbers turns out to be different but corresponds to the sequence for seed(13). Right ?

Answer (score 0):

No, `random` does not reseed unless you tell it to.

`random` implements the `Random` class for its operations. This class seeds itself on initialization - either with a default seed or one you supply. You can reseed with the `.seed` method but that's not typically done with a `Random` object you create yourself.

The module then creates one instance of `Random` and assigns its methods to module level variables. When you call `random.gauss`, that's really a method on this object. This object uses the default seed algorithm. If you don't want the default algorithm or if you want to seed with a known value for reproducible random numbers, you can call `random.seed(yourvalue)`.

But that whole reproducibility thing is dodgy on the default random object. Other things in your system also calling random will mess up your supposedly reproducible numbers. If you want reproducibility (maybe for testing?), create your own `random.Random` objects.