# Maximum Value of numpy.random.seed

Tags: numpy, random, numpy-ndarray, random-seed

Could we alter the maximum possible value of numpy.random.seed ? Normally, the seed takes values from 0 to 2^{32} - 1. I was wanting to make it to go to 2^{64} - 1. Is there any way to do this ?

I am worried if altering the maximum value of the seed in the mtrand.pyx can be compatible with the remainder of the Python installation instance. I changed the upper limit, but it seems that the seed value still does not go above 2^{32} - 1, instead it just repeats from 0 once the upper limit is reached.

Comment: "*I was wanting to make it to go to 2^{64} - 1*" -> Why? This looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I imagine the size of the seed makes sense in terms of how the RNG works, trying to force a value could just be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for modern pseudo-random number generators, [the seed and the state are related but different concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505649/2166798). Setting the seed will achieve reproducibility, but for full control you need the state.

Using the `seed()` interface means you're generating pseudo-random numbers in legacy mode (to maintain backwards compatibility with older versions of numpy), and are constrained to a single integer's worth of control of the state. The recommendation these days is that you should be writing new code based on the updated [Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) approach. There's lots of documentation at that link to tell you how to achieve reproducible streams of randomness, and how to safely construct multiple reproducible streams for parallelization.

If you insist on sticking with legacy mode and really think you need full control over the state of the Mersenne Twister, you can use [set_state](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.set_state.html#numpy.random.RandomState.set_state) which gives you control over the full 19937 bits of internal state.

Comment: @eyah Actually it did. It warned OP against using deprecated approaches, but told them how they could control 19937 bits of initialization if they insisted. That certainly exceeds the 2^32 - 1 that OP expressed concern about. It also pointed out that seeding is about reproducibility, not about degree of randomness.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum possible value for numpy.random.seed is determined by the underlying random number generator used by NumPy, which is typically based on the Mersenne Twister algorithm. The Mersenne Twister has a period of 2^19937 - 1, meaning it can generate a sequence of 19937-bit numbers before repeating. However, the seed itself is typically limited to a 32-bit integer value, ranging from 0 to 2^32 - 1.

Unfortunately, altering the maximum value of the seed to 2^64 - 1 is not possible within the existing NumPy implementation. The seed value will wrap around to 0 once the maximum limit is reached because it is stored as a 32-bit integer.

If you require a larger seed range, you would need to explore alternative random number generators or libraries that support larger seed values. However, it's worth noting that the 32-bit seed range is generally sufficient for most use cases and provides a vast number of possible seed values to generate diverse random sequences.

Comment: Seeding has nothing to do with the diversity of the random sequences produced, it's about reproducibility.